# Creating variable of team demographics- similarity/dissimilarity

Tags: spss

I wish to create a variable depicting similarity with respect to race to team members. In other words, I want to know of the people an individual shares a manager with, what percentage of the team is of the same race?

The variables I currently have are participant id, participant race, manager id, manager race, and team size. I know the racial breakdown of the teams, but I need the percentage of similar others in a team for each participant (in one column, not across columns split by race).

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the number of participants of the same race for each participants, then divide that in the team size to get the ratio.
In the following code I assume you have the team ID although you didn't mention that in your post:

```
aggregate out=* mode=addvariables /break team_id participant_race /NRaceInTeam=n.
compute PRaceInTeam=NRaceInTeam/Team_Size.
```